# How to implement this function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Wonderful thing about Haskell. The type of a function almost dictates its implementation. That's the case for this one, but... my brain just isn't wrapping around the nested function thing here:

```
mkDyn :: (Typeable a) => ((a -> IO()) -> IO ()) -> ((Dynamic -> IO()) -> IO ())
```

The only question is how to handle error handling in the fromDynamic call that will be required, but... I can deal with that once I have the rest figured out. I'm guessing there will need to be something like the following somewhere. But I can't seem to get the wrapper lambda stuff figured out.

```
case fromDynamic x of
  Just x -> f x
  Nothing -> undefined -- TODO
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know Haskell had dynamic type support, let alone that it was [available in base](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Dynamic.html).  Learn something new every day.

Comment: @Joey IIRC there is even a library to write imperative-style code with easy assignment operators, but I forgot where. I think it was mentioned once on Planet Haskell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you want `toDyn`, not `fromDynamic`.  So let's do this slowly:

```
mkDyn :: Typeable a =>
         ((a -> IO ()) -> IO ())
      -> (Dynamic -> IO ())
      -> IO ()
mkDyn k f = ...
```

Our return type should be `IO ()` and we can obtain that either by calling `k` or `f`.  Calling `f` doesn't help us much, because we would somehow materialise a `Dynamic`, but we cannot do that (sensibly) from `k`.  So we want to call `k`.  `k` needs another function as its argument, so lets start like this:

```
mkDyn k f = k (\a -> ...)
```

So the function's argument is `Typeable a => a -> IO ()`.  We don't have a function of that type, but we have a function of type `Dynamic -> IO ()`.  Because of the `Typeable` constraint we can use `toDyn` to turn our `a` into `Dynamic` and get:

```
mkDyn k f = k (\a -> f (toDyn a))
```

There are simpler implementations (e.g., `return ()` or `k (\a -> return ())`, but this one appears to make sense.

Comment: @rampion Two can play that game! `mkDyn = (. (. toDyn))`.

Comment: I tend to prefer the pointed versions.  I only use point-free style if things are truly just a simple pipeline.  Anything (even slightly) more complicated and I would regret it the next time I read the code.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner using sections for function composition, twice? I think my brain just exploded a little.

Comment: I love stackoverflow, especially for Haskell questions. Brilliant, and thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I cheated and used the [Djinn program](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1178).

I first generalized the type given:

```
f :: (a -> c)
  -> ((a -> b) -> b)
  -> ((c -> b) -> b)
```

The `(a -> c)` represents the [`toDyn` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Dynamic.html#v:toDyn) function, and `c` represents `Dynamic`.  `b` represents `IO ()`.

Djinn's result was surprisingly simple:

```
@djinn (a -> c) -> ((a -> b) -> b) -> ((c -> b) -> b)
f a b c = b (\ d -> c (a d))
```

Making it more specific (by replacing the `(a -> c)` with the `toDyn` function), we get:

```
mkDyn :: (Typeable a) => ((a -> IO()) -> IO ()) -> ((Dynamic -> IO()) -> IO ())
mkDyn b c = b (\ d -> c (toDyn d))
```

which matches [nominolo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373421/how-to-implement-this-function-in-haskell/7373539#7373539).

Comment: Does this prove that nominolo is a djinn?